# Не работает localStorage в IE11

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Почему мой Internet Explorer 11 не работает с `localStorage`, хотя вроде должен?

Этот код даёт в результате `undefined` для `window.localStorage`:

HTML:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = window.localStorage;
```

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, Вы пытаетесь использовать `localStorage` в локальном файле файловой системы. Так вот, он там не работает:

> In IE attempting to access localStorage on HTML files served from the file system results in the localStorage object being undefined

Другие особенности и различия Вы можете почитать на этом сайте: http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage *(внизу страницы, в вкладке "Known issues")*.

Answer (score 0):

Внутри элемента с id="result" должна появиться строка "[object Storage]".

Может быть https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41468?